# USB bus 1 deregistered and all usb ports are not working

Tags: linux, usb

xhci_hcd is deregistered, I tried for days to fix this but I couldn't

```
$ dmesg | grep xhci
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't setup: -110
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: USB bus 1 deregistered
xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: init 0000:00:14.0 fail, -110
xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:00:14.0 failed with error -110
```

tried booting with grub and uefi, the same error occurs,

N.B. I can still boot from USB! despite that it is deregistered after the kernel is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details as to your hardware but since the XHCI driver is deregistered you'll have to get the info from the manufacturer or another OS.  Have you tried booting a newer or older OS?  As regards a couple of points of confusion,

> N.B. I can still boot from USB! despite that it is deregistered after the kernel is loaded

BIOS usb drivers are reading the USB device during boot but once the OS loads its own driver you lose the USB XHCI driver then your boot file system becomes inaccessible.

> tried booting with grub and uefi, the same error occurs,

Both use the BIOS usb drivers.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, yes I have tried other OSs and had no luck. I am currently stuck with a totally bricked system (that happened after a power loss had occured).